# Excel : Searching a Value in Matrix with range on both dimension

Tags: excel

I would like to search for 2 values within 2 ranges and expect an answer. I have tried looking at my places but of no help. Can you help?

[image: Range]

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your efforts.

Comment: Have a look at the [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) and [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) functions. Also could you have a read of [ASK] and [MCVE] please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is better to keep same order on rows and columns.
Let-s supose we have the following table:
[image: excel table]

The formula will lok like this:

```
=INDEX(D4:I7;MATCH(C11;B4:B7);MATCH(D11;D2:I2))
```

Take a look at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/look-up-values-with-vlookup-index-or-match-7144ef3f-e322-4f95-9e96-f1d743270438

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Virgil Ionescu and Darren Bartup Cook. The solution of Lookup along with Match worked perfectly well. I was just getting confused because I was working on range.

Below is correct formula. I also had to rearrange my table to ensure the array values were in descending order.

=INDEX(G41:L44,MATCH(F49,E41:E44,1),MATCH(G49,G39:L39,1))